# Width of Parent Div = Maximum Width of Child Divs?

Tags: html, css

Can I make the width of a parent div be automatically equal to the maximum width of its children? I.e. I want the the parent to be as wide as the widest child, no wider. I can accept both pure css and javascript solutions.

In particular, [I have a parent div with two floating divs inside](http://jsfiddle.net/mgauci/yXNnd/8/). I want the parent div to resize when the right div drops below (if the window becomes too narrow), to make the background of the parent div display properly.

Thank you!

```
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="logo-div">
        <img class="logo" src="http://bit.ly/1qCKrtJ" />
    </div>
    <div class="text-div">
        <h4 style="display: inline;">Because Sometimes It Takes a Village</h4><br />
        What about robots the size of tea cups that scoot around on tiny wheels, snapping pictures with miniature cameras and keeping track of where they are in relation to dozens of others?
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make the container `display:inline-block`

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yXNnd/10/)

```
.container {
    background: green;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 430px;
    display: inline-block; /* add this */
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in this case unfortunately: http://picpaste.com/Capture-cXRMo8bd.PNG

Comment: Sorry about that. What I mean is that in the case of the screenshot the green should not extend beyond the blue. I want the the parent to be as wide as the widest child, no wider.